# Postioning of text not working correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, if-statement, quirks-mode

I have an if statement that decides what to render the page in.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if (NS4) {
    document.write('<LAYER NAME="floatlayer" LEFT="22" TOP="60">');
}

if ((IE4) || (NS6)) {
    document.write('<div id="floatlayer" style="position:absolute; left:22; top:62;">');
}
</script>
```

Now I know this works because this has been the code for previous versions and I had no problems.  I created a page that forces the page to render as the most up to date viewer possilbe(IE10,Chrome1) I used a simple Meta tag to do so;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

When I go on IE and switch it to Quirks mode the page works correctly and everything is lined up properly but anything other than Quirks the page is broken.  What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure the browser detection is working fine?

Comment: @Einacio This has been the code for a few years and has never changed only thing that has been added is the meta tag so I’m pretty sure the browser detection is working.

Comment: unless the browser detection depends on some property only available on quirks mode and the meta tag breaks it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was as simple as removing the

```
<script language="JavaScript">

if (NS4) {
    document.write('<LAYER NAME="floatlayer" LEFT="22" TOP="60">');
}

if ((IE4) || (NS6)) {
    document.write('<div id="floatlayer" style="position:absolute; left:22; top:62;">');
}
</script>
```

and creating a class for the table.  Then I set the properties in the .css file and the text positioned properly.

Answer (score 0):

`22` is not a valid value for `left` in CSS.  You probably want `22px` and similar for the `top` value.  Browsers will accept unitless lengths in some properties in quirks mode, though; see http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-unitless-length-quirk.  That's why things work for you in quirks mode.